# Creating a button to scroll UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have a button connected from storyboard that I want to scroll my horizontally scrolling collection view one item to the right when pressed. Here is the code I came up with:

```
- (IBAction)rightButton:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    NSIndexPath* newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];


    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:newIndexPath
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                    animated:YES];
```

}

However, this is creating a crash, with the error

```
 -[__NSArrayI row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178232540
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178232540'
```

I suspect the problem is that this code is more for a TableView and it doesn't like the section park in there.

Can someone help me out with this and figure out why I get an error? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indexPathsForSelectedItems` method name has an extra `s` in it, `Paths` not `Path`, which indicates that it returns an `NSArray` of index paths, not a single index path. Hence the solution is to change these lines

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
NSIndexPath* newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
```

to this

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
if ( indexPaths.count > 0 )
{
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = indexPaths[0];
    NSInteger oldRow = oldIndexPath.row;
    newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldRow + 1 inSection:oldIndexPath.section];
}
```

Comment: Hey, so I changed my code to that and it doesn't like the addition there. I get the error `Arithmetic on pointer to interface "id", which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform`

Comment: @Deannakov -- Yes, it doesn't like the fact that the object from the array is of type `id`. Assigning (and implicitly converting) the object to an `NSIndexPath *` helps keep the compiler happy. I've updated the answer to illustrate.

Comment: Ok - so this is working, scrolling one item to the right of the item selected. The problem is that it isn't *selecting* the item to the right of the item selected, but that's on me: my code was only scrolling it. Thanks for the help! If you have any insight on getting the selection to change that's great, but I'll do a little research.

Comment: Oh, that was easy - just found the `selectItemAtIndexPath` method.